# Changing the button name and functionality in image picker modal view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I change the 'Choose' button name and functionality in the image picker modal view?

I want to change the name to 'Upload' button, to upload a movie to web.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method as:

```
-(void)saveImages:(id)sender
{

}
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationItem *ipcNavBarTopItem;


    // add done button to right side of nav bar
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Title"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(saveImages:)];

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    [bar setHidden:NO];
    ipcNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
    ipcNavBarTopItem.title = @"any Title";
    ipcNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer, but after implamenting your code, i still have same result. After pressing "choose" button, simulator hangs with note "Compressing Video...". How i can fix it ?